# Are hacking questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, scope

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131020/error-pops-up-after-clicking-button) that was seemingly innocent at first:

[image]

I became slightly suspicious of the intent of the application the question was about when I saw one of the provided screenshots of the code was poorly censored and pointed to Sony's Entertainment Network's login page:

[image]

I solved the OP's problem asked in the question, but however was asked about a further issue that was being caused by Sony's security measures. In response I asked the OP about their intentions, and they sidestepped the question:

[image]

I viewed their screen and my suspicions were confirmed:

[image]

According to the OP, retrieving a stolen list of emails and passwords for login to Sony's systems and systematically attempting to login to each one is not considered hacking, but however my opinion differs. It might not be hacking, but it certainly is illegal.

***Are questions based around hacking/computer malpractice allowed on Stack Overflow?***

I'm not sure if flagging the question for deletion via a custom flag is the right thing to do here.

I believe that these type of questions are forbidden on Stack Overflow and many users may feel uncomfortable aiding a hacking/cracking program such as the one documented here, and many users (including myself) may have certain standards disallowing them from aiding hackers:

[image]

Comment: Yes they are allowed.

Comment: They may be allowed, I just regularly downCloseVote them.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel This question is not about viruses/malware, so that duplicate does not help.

Comment: @cybermonkey: what is the difference in ethical dilemma between viruses, malware and hacking?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel From the apparent duplicate: http://puu.sh/eZ149/a720cf561c.png. This user breaks *both* of those, implying their question is strictly off-topic.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel This question is mainly about the question that was asked, and not about hacking questions in general, therefore this question is not a duplicate as it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: that question should have been closed moments after posting.  Poorly posted, poorly presented, zero effort,  a clear NRE dupe... *then* there is the hacking element,

Comment: @Plutonix True, but then ironically I edited the question to clear it up before I knew its true intent , which probably helped keep it alive. The hacking element wasn't apparent until the OP pretty much 'handed it over on a plate'.

Comment: your edits just made clear that there was another reason to close it and move on: NRE Dupe #109,834

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It's too late, but viruses and hacking are different. In other words, "every virus is a kind of *hacking*, but not every *hacking* is a virus". You can hack an Instagram account with the help of coding to obtain their password. Can this be called a virus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to my question is *no*.
From the (wrongly in my opinion) proposed duplicate:

[image]

That question breaks *both* those 'rules' and as such, the question is outside the scope and is strictly off-topic.

As Plutonix mentioned, the question should've been closed/removed *before* its malicious intent was realised as:

- The question is poorly researched
- Was too broad as the question doesn't (at first) have the information required to answer the question
- Is poorly researched and no research was given
- Is a duplicate of the many `NullReferenceException` questions out there

Comment: The dupe seems appropriate if you got your answer *from* the dupe...